# Bunifu cannot access non-static property Visible

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a menu which has 3 tabs. Login, News and website. I created user control and named it LoginTab.cs now I put the login panels in there [LoginTab.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRn2D.png), [NewsTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFx3z.png). Now I am trying to make it visible and invisible depending on what tab people click. So if someone clicks news then the LoginTab goes away and shows the News tab. My problem is that I can't used LoginTab.Visible because its showing me "Cannot access non-static property 'Visible' in static context. How would I do this?

Main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using UHWID;

namespace AnixLoader
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        bool username;
        bool usergroup;

        String SimpleUID = UHWIDEngine.SimpleUid;

        String AdvancedUID = UHWIDEngine.AdvancedUid;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Sdads_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CloseMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0); // Closes Menu
        }

        private void BunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginTab.Visible = true;
            NewsTab.Visible = false;
        }

        private void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginTab.Visible = false;
            NewsTab.Visible = true;
        }

        private void BtnMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (sidemenu.Width == 60)
            {
                //EXPAND
                // 1. Expand the panel , w = 300
                // 2. Show Logo
                sidemenu.Visible = false;
                sidemenu.Width = 300;
                PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidemenu);
                LogoAnimator.ShowSync(Anix_Logo);
            }
            else
            {
                //MINIMIZE
                //Using Bunifu Animator
                // 1. Hide the logo
                // 2. Slide the panel, w = 60

                LogoAnimator.Hide(Anix_Logo);
                sidemenu.Visible = false;
                sidemenu.Width = 60;
                PanelAnimator.ShowSync(sidemenu);
            }
        }

        private void MainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

LoginTab.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnixLoader
{
    public partial class LoginTab : UserControl
    {
        public LoginTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginTab_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LoginText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Password_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by changing from this

```
private void BunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginTab.Visible = true;
            NewsTab.Visible = false;
        }

        private void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginTab.Visible = false;
            NewsTab.Visible = true;
        }
```

to this

```
private void BunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // Log in button
            this.MainPanel.Controls.Clear();
            this.MainPanel.Controls.Add(new LoginTab());
        }

        private void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // News button
            this.MainPanel.Controls.Clear();
            this.MainPanel.Controls.Add(new NewsTab());
        }
```